# Filling an array in such a way that each element equal to minimum sum of two numbers such that

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array (contains only **positive** integers) that already has the first **k** elements: **a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, .... a<sub>k</sub>**.

I need to fill the remaining **(n - k)** elements (the array has **n** elements in total).

The value of **n** is about **10 ^ 3** and **1 <= k <= n**.

The value of each **a<sub>i</sub>** is the minimum sum of two numbers such that the sum of positions of those two numbers is equal to **i**.


Here is the pseudocode (my algorithm):

```
for i = k + 1 to n
  a[i] = max_value
  for j = 1 to (i / 2)
    a[i] = min(a[i], a[j] + a[i - j])
```

Time complexity: **O(n ^ 2)**


The question: Is there any other way to do this faster?

I'm looking for any data structures or algorithms that can find the value of each **a<sub>i</sub>** in less than **O(n)**.


P/S: This is a procedure in my program so I need to do this as fast as possible.

Comment: If it's real code, what are you really trying to do? This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/13).

Comment: I added description, and that's my code (straightforward)

Comment: I looked at your edit. Your question is still way too abstract. What real problem is your code trying to solve?

Comment: I don't have a strict proof but I have a strong feeling that O(n) can not be improved. Still a good question IMHO +1

Comment: The real problem is: given a rectangle of size n x m, you have to cut this rectangle into many squares; each cut must be parallel with one of the two pairs of sides of the rectangle; in each cut, you can split the rectangle into two parts (two smaller rectangles), and keep cutting them (the two smaller rectangles), until there are only squares; there are many ways to cut and you have to find a way that the remaining squares is minimum.

Comment: This problem is a bit similar to the "tiling rectangles with squares", the difference is the "cut". It can be solved by dynamic programming with complexity O(n * m * (m + n)) but that's too much for n and m ~ 10 ^ 3. The pseudocode is one of the inner loop.

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but if you replace operation `+` with `*` and `min` with `+`, and if you also have `a1 = a2 = 1` (and you're looking for `a3,...`), you end up with the sequence of [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). In that case, you get a recurrence relation that includes a [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), so you can use [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) and get a closed-form solution. Unfortunately, all that is not possible in your problem.

Comment: Each of the array elements is strictly positive?

Comment: @enofwiz The first thing that comes to my mind is to split the rectangle into a maximal square shunted against one end (i.e., with length `min(m, n)`) and a second rectangle, recurring on the second if it's not square, else terminating. I have no idea whether this will produce the optimal solution, but my intuition tells me it's worth a try.

Comment: @StuartOlsen Quite interestingly, though maybe unsurprisingly, doing this for a rectangle with sides whose lengths are the `n`th and `n+1`th Fibonacci numbers takes... `n` cuts.

Comment: @StuartOlsen Assume `m > n`, cutting the rectangle of size `m x n` into a square of size `n x n` and a smaller rectangle of size `(m - n) x n` is optimal for most cases (about 80%), here are some exceptions, `m = n + 1` such as `9 x 8`, `10 x 9`, etc.. For `9 x 8`, it should be cut into `8 x 4` and `8 x 5`, not `8 x 8` and `1 x 8`.

Comment: @enofwiz I figured as much. OT: while my approach's characteristics aren't optimal, [they are interesting](http://i.imgur.com/OYnnQRg.jpg). In particular, there are certain proportions which have very "short" solutions, and proportions very near those have _much_ longer solutions. Given which proportions are which, I'm immediately struck by the similarities to musical harmonies. [Here's the program](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/56b6d85022966a1a325c) I hacked together to make that, if you want to play with it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please could you give some examples?

Comment: @ColonelPanic: For example: we have `a1 = 10, a2 = 6, a3 = 4` and we need to compute `a4, a5,` .... Here are the calculations: a4 = min(a1 + a3, a2 + a2) = 12; a5 = min(a1 + a4, a2 + a3) = 10; a6 = min(a1 + a5, a2 + a4, a3 + a3) = 8... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase your program speed by using threads to run your check for the minimum value in parallel. For example you could run 4 threads each of which checks 1/4 of the range of j. This will improve the speed marginally, but your algorithm will still take O(n^2) running time.

I agree with the comment that you most likely can't get beyond O(n^2). So your best bet will probably be to try things like this to optimize your code to reduce the coefficient in front of that n^2.

Answer (score 0):

## Idea 1

AFAICT this will not give a guaranteed improvement on O(n^2), but it should bring the number of inner loop cycles down *a lot* in practice.  The basic idea is that we can test pairs in the inner loop in a different order that enables us to finish early a lot of the time.  Specifically we first make a sorted list of positions of the numbers and store this in `s[]`, so that `a[s[i]]` is the ith smallest number in `a[]`.  Then in the main inner loop, we form pair-sums in increasing order of the first term by using `a[s[j]]` instead of `a[j]` (and `a[i - s[j]]` instead of `a[i - j]`).  This gives us 2 ways to **stop the inner loop early:**

1. If `a[s[j]] >= a[i]`, then we can stop because every later sum must be larger, since the first term of each of them (`a[s[j+1]]` etc.) must be at least as large as the best solution so far (already in `a[i]`), and the other term can never be negative.
2. If `a[i - s[j]] <= a[s[j]]` (that is, if the "partner" of the next smallest number is less than or equal to it), we can stop, for a more complicated reason.  Suppose to the contrary that there was some better pair-sum `a[s[m]] + a[i - s[m]]` later on (i.e. `m > j`).  We know the first term, `a[s[m]]`, must be at least as large as our current first term `a[s[j]]` because we're accessing first terms in increasing order, and `m > j`; therefore, for the pair-sum `a[s[m]] + a[i - s[m]]` to be better (i.e. less) than `a[s[j]] + a[i - s[j]]`, it must be that its second term, `a[i - s[m]]`, is less than our current second term, `a[i - s[j]]`.  (This is not a sufficient condition, but that doesn't matter here.)  But since we have just observed that `a[i - s[j]] <= a[s[j]]`, we know that `a[i - s[m]] < a[s[j]]` too, which means that `a[i - s[m]]` must have appeared *as a first term* in a pair-sum that we already processed earlier on!  That contradicts `m > j`, meaning that no such better pair-sum can exist, so we can safely stop.

I expect the second condition to remove a lot of inner loop cycles; the first will probably only help much on datasets where there are a few small numbers and a lot of very high numbers, and it is possible to cover most positions with pair-sums of the small numbers.

Bonus efficiency: If we implement the second condition above then we don't actually need a separate `j < i / 2` loop termination test, since after examining any `i / 2 + 1` pair-sums, we must have encountered at least one pair-sum twice (once with the first and second terms swapped), and this will cause condition 2 to fire and exit the loop.

Pseudocode:

```
s[1 .. k] = 1 .. k
sort s using comparator function comp(i, j) { a[i] < a[j] }

for i = k + 1 to n
  a[i] = max_value
  for (j = 1; a[s[j]] < a[i] && a[i - s[j]] > a[s[j]]; ++j)
    a[i] = min(a[i], a[s[j]] + a[i - s[j]])
```